# При зпросе не выдаёт значение из БД, PHP

Tags: php, авторизация

Я только учусь, первый раз делаю регистрацию и авторизацию. Регистрация рабтает нормально, есть поблема с авторизацией. Должно сверить пароль который ввел пользоватеь с тем что в БД. Если перед проверкой вывести оба значения видно что пароль с БД не выдает, поэтому авторизация не проходит. Подскажите что не так:

```
<?php
    // ПЕРЕВІРКА
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$connect = mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","vertrigo","my_bd");
if (!$connect) {
    mysqli_error();
}

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $pswd = $_POST['pswd'];
    $pswd_again = $_POST['pswd_again'];
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $user_surname = $_POST['user_surname'];
    $user_age = $_POST['user_age'];
    $user_origin = $_POST['user_origin'];
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO users (login, password, name, surname, age, origin) VALUES ('$login','$pswd','$user_name','$user_surname','$user_age','$user_origin')");
}

mysqli_close($connect);


    // ПРОВЕРКА
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$connect = mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","vertrigo","my_bd");
if (!$connect) {
    mysqli_error();
}



if (isset($_POST['enter'])) {
    $enter_login = $_POST['enter_login'];
    $enter_pswd = $_POST['enter_pswd'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($connect, " SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'login' = '$enter_login' ");
    $user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

    echo $user_data['password'];
        //echo $user_data   ['password'];
        //echo $enter_pswd;

    if ($user_data['password'] == $enter_pswd) {
        echo 'HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO'; 
    }
}

mysqli_close($connect);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_array` массив возвращает.

Так что, надо:

```
if ($user_data[0]['password'] == $enter_pswd) {
    echo 'HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO'; 
}
```

Comment: не помогло. 'HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO' не выводит